# Combination Probability: Chances of two particular people winning a raffle prize

Tags: probability, combinations

So say there was an annual raffle. Each person receives one ticket only (i.e. you can't win more than one prize). If there are 510 ticketed people (including 1xFrank and 1xSally) and 32 prizes are drawn without replacement, what are the odds of Frank AND Sally BOTH winning a prize each?

Now, what are the chances of them both winning such an event two years in a row?

NOW, how would one suspect the raffle was rigged in some way? Is there a way to give quality assurance to these things?

I am completely out of my depth with this question but would appreciate a thoughtful answer. :)

Comment: Do you really mean [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds), or do you mean [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability)?

Comment: I wasn't aware that odds and probability were different, sorry! Good to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

*chances* in the heading, *odds* in the question, I'll calculate the *probability* (Btw, *chance* is used loosely for *probability*, which is not the same as *odds*)

P(both win) = $\dfrac{32}{510}\dfrac{31}{509} = Z,\;say$

P(both win for two years in a row) = $Z^2$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the "210" and "209". I assume you meant 510 and 509? That is a very simple intuitive reply, I always had trouble understanding probability but it is intriguing all the same

Comment: Sorry, typo corrected. Another way of getting the same result would be $\dfrac {\dbinom {32}{2}}{\dbinom{510}{2}}$

Comment: Why isn't the answer $\frac{{510 \choose 30}}{{510 \choose 32}}$? Am I interpreting this wrong? It is past my bedtime, so my logic may be off,  but I figured the number of (unordered) groups of $32$ people that contain both Frank and Sally is ${510 \choose 30}$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling: The fallacy in your formula is that it assumes that **the** duo are already in the prizewinner list. Try both formulas for tickets = $6$, prizes = $3$

Comment: My formula is only assuming the duo are among the $510$ who've been ticketed. If we enumerate the $6$ ticketed people in your example with $\{1,\ldots 6\}$ and assume Frank is $1$ and Sally is $2$, the number of ways to choose $3$ people among the $6$ who've been ticketed that include $\{1,2\}$ is ${6-2 \choose 1}$. The number of ways to choose $3$ prizewinners all together is ${6 \choose 3}$

Comment: @MatthewPilling: Let's go back to your original formulation. After you have allotted one prize each to Frank and Sally, there are only 508 tickets left to distribute the remaining 30 prizes, so your formulation should have been $\frac{\binom{508}{30}}{\binom{510}{32}}$.But why go about it in this way when just$\frac{32}{510}\frac{31}{509}$ does it so easily.

Comment: Oh my goodness you're right I should have had ${508 \choose 30}.$ Thank you